# SQLAlchemy and scalar values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have simple question regarding SQLAlchemy, is it possible to get the rows from the result as scalars instead of tuples? In other words I want an equivalent to:

```
[i[0] for i in self.archive.query(IRTerm.term).distinct()]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No built in way in SQLAlchemy, but with python it isn't too hard. The example you gave works fine. You can also do `map(itemgetter(0), query)` or `for value, in query:`.

Comment: Thank you, I just asked if there is some builtin way. So I'll continue using the solution that I mentioned.

Answer (score -2):

Since 0.6.5 you can use `query.as_scalar` ([ref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar)).

Comment: This actually returns the SELECT statement.